# In heroku CLI with .htpasswd command typed password is not showing

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli, heroku-connect

I wanted to create .htpasswd file for simple auth.
In cli i typed:

```
heroku run htpasswd -c .htpasswd [by]
```

And then ut asked me to type New Password but while typing password I wasn't able too see anything.

I also tried to type password as usual and hit enter but in sign in password doesn't match.

I typed wallpaper.com as password two times but in while signing password doesn't match...

Comment: normal. Just type as usual and hit enter.

Comment: @tinnguyen Yes I did that but while sign in typed password doesn't match!

Comment: In logs it says password doesn't match for user by.